# Groovy read feature methods with reflection

Tags: java, reflection, groovy, spock

I am trying to use reflection to read fields and methods from a groovy class. Everything works great expect my feature methods like this:

```
def "do something"(){
//
}
```

Using reflection I cannot find this "method name". 
Is there any way to read these feature methods by reflection?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This might help you http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN3535-Reflection

Comment: Are you talking about a Spock specification? In regular Groovy code, you can find this method name using reflection (and it will fail to compile/run in some cases).

Comment: Exactly. Thanks for the link. I read some more about groovy and loaded a compiled groovy spock class into the Java Decompiler to "see" what groovy created ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find it with `metaClass`:

```
class Lol {
    def 'do something'(){}
}

assert new Lol().metaClass.methods.find { it.name == 'do something' }
```